# setCanelable for intent dialog in android

Tags: android

I'm using an activity with theme.Dialog style for show my custom dialog,i wanna set canceleable to my dialog same as the time we using alertdialogs,how can i do this?
here is my code for showing dialog

```
Intent tt=new Intent(this,reportActivity.class);
startActivity(tt);
```

and this is the way i make my activity to be dialog when started :

```
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:name=".reportActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_report" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if this is a true dialog then you can do something like this:

Dialog dialog = new Dialog ();

dialog.setCancelable(true);

This would mean any touch outside of the dialog would dismiss it.

What I like to do is have a DialogHelperClass which you code all the different types of dialogs you want, e.g. different amounts of buttons etc, and then pass in Context and a boolean called "isCancelable" which then you can pass a value through:

dialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: no,it's a activity then i used like a dialog and can't instantiate like a dialog,is there any other way?